# How to calculate how much inward force is neccessary crush an object into a black hole

Tags: forces, black-holes, pressure

I would you list some ways I could determine how much force is required to crush an object into a black hole, web sites that show this would also be helpful In fact moreso.

Comment: Note that list based questions are generally considered off topic as *too broad*.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation You essentially use G.R. to see when the pressure of the object you are trying to "collapse" becomes negative. If  your object is spherically symmetric, you can use the TOV equation to show that this collapse into a "black hole" occurs for $R > 9/8 R_{s}$, where $R_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius. The spherically symmetric case is nice because of symmetry, but for general  geometries, it is *slightly* more difficult.

Comment: Don't be thrown off by the wording of the question. It isn't a bad one. @IkjyotSinghKohli should write his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know the pressure, not the force. The way you do crush something into a black hole is to start with a massive star, at least 1.4 times as big as the Sun. Pressure is very high in the center, but ongoing fusion helps sustain it against collapse. So you wait for the star to exhaust its fuel. As the core cools, the weight of the star above it crushes it.

Typically people don't talk about the pressure needed as much as the minimum size of the star. For example, that is what [this site](http://www.phys.vt.edu/~jhs/faq/blackholes.html) does.

If a star isn't quite big enough to collapse to a black hole, it becomse a neutron star. People do talk about the pressure in the middle of a neutron star. If the pressure was any bigger than this (because the star was bigger), it would collapse to a black hole. So the answer, according to the Wikipedia [Neutron Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star) article, is $1.6×10^{35} Pa$

You might also be interested in [this site](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2008/10/30/ten-things-you-dont-know-about-black-holes/#.WU2ovcZGmUk), even though it doesn't have numbers.

Comment: $1.4M_\odot$ sounds a bit low, even if the star undergoes direct core collapse rather than ejecting a lot of mass in a supernova explosion.

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in my comment above, you must use the TOV equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation

Integrating this equation / solving the ODE, one obtains for the pressure of the spherically symmetric object at some distance $r$, :

$p(r) = \mu \left[  \frac{\sqrt{1-r_s /  R} - \sqrt{1 - r_s r^2 / R^3}}{ \sqrt{1 - r_s r^2 / R^3} - 3 \sqrt{1 - r_s / R}}\right]$

where $\mu$ is the mass density of the object, and $r_s$ I have denoted as the Schwarzschild radius: $r_s = 2G M$.

Now, look at this result: it is only valid for when $r \leq R$. The pressure at $r=0$ which is what you're concerned with is:

$p(0) = \mu \left[ \frac{\sqrt{1 - r_s / R} - 1}{1 - 3 \sqrt{1 - r_s /R}}     \right]$.

This becomes negative, $p(0) < 0$, when the denominator of this expression becomes negative, since $\mu > 0$ by assumption. So, this becomes negative when:

$1 - 3 \sqrt{1 - r_s / R} < 0$.

This inequality is essentially the collapse condition. So, your object will collapse into a "black hole" as long as this inequality is satisfied.

You essentially use G.R. to see when the pressure of the object you are trying to "collapse" becomes negative. If your object is spherically symmetric, you can use the TOV equation to show that this collapse into a "black hole" occurs for $R>9/8 r_s$, where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius. The spherically symmetric case is nice because of symmetry, but for general geometries, it is slightly more difficult. This hopefully answers your question. (On a side note, one can always have black holes without any such notions of things collapsing: just take a Minkowski spacetime and cut out a hole, you'll get the Schwarzschild metric!)

Comment: I think you have a typo in this equation: $R>9/8 r_s$. Shouldn't it be $R<9/8 r_s$?

Answer (score 0):

As per my back envelope calculation, we need this much "pressure" to crush anything that has mass $m$ into a black hole [1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/367310408_Gravitational_pressure_of_a_black_hole)

$P = m^2 \frac {c^6} {h^2G}$,

where all constants hold its usual meaning.

This clearly shows the pressure needed is only function of mass $m$.

[1](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/367310408_Gravitational_pressure_of_a_black_hole) Kapil P. Chandra, Gravitational pressure of a black hole, DOI: 10.13140/RG.2.2.20473.34409

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/402003)